# Valid For Loop - but why? for(;;System.out.println("a"));

Tags: java, for-loop

Can someone explain to me why the statement below is a valid for loop? My java book states:-

for(initialization;expression;iteration);

I understand the first two can be left blank and create an infinite loop but why can I type a statement like System.out.println("a"); ?

```
for(;;System.out.println("a"));
```

Comment: Why can you do `i++`? What's the difference between `i++` and `System.out.println(wtv)`?

Comment: initialization = declaration or statement, iteration = statement.

Answer (score 2):

Because the iteration part of the loop requires a statement, any statement. And `System.out.println("a")` is a statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a for loop such as

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  // operations
}
```

in terms of a while loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
  // operations
  i++;
}
```

Adding `i++` in the iteration part of the for loop is a way of saying "execute `i++` at the end of every iteration", as shown by the while loop example.